# How do you redirect a 404.3 message in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, custom-error-pages, custom-errors

In the case where a particular ActiveX control has not been installed on my user's workstation, attempting to load a particular file extension (e.g. "*.ica") causes a 404.3 status to be thrown.  I would like to redirect this to an actual page instead of having the user see either the textual content of the file (lower versions of IE) or the 404.3 page (higher versions).  I know how to do a custom errors redirect:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="pageNotfound.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

but I can't put 404.3 in the statusCode because it only takes integers, and there doesn't seem to be any other place to put the ".3".  Besides what is shown above, the customErrors.errors node has only a few "lock" attributes available.  Is there a way to catch a 404.3?

ETA: Since posting this question I have determined that IIS can be instructed to handle Custom Errors.  I have tried this in IIS 7.5, but even setting the desired custom error page for 404.3 does not actually *work*.

[image]

It is still redirecting to the default 404.3 error page.